# Implications of Positive Definiteness

Tags: matrices

Assuming I have a complex non-symmetric matrix $A$ which is "positive definite" in the sense that $\Re(x^*Ax) > 0$.

A necessary and sufficient condition for $A$ to be "positive definite" is that the Hermitian part $A_H = A+A^*$ is positive definite (A^* is the conjugate transpose). (Source Wolfram Alpha)

Now I am wondering: is it also necessary and/or sufficient that the Hermitian matrix $A_{H2} = AA^*$ is positive definite?

Somehow I think that I have seen this somewhere before, and it would be really useful if it were true. ;)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Cheers,
Christoph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AA^*$ is *always* positive semidefinite, and positive definite iff $A$ is invertible. Which is *far* weaker than any form of positive definiteness of $A$ itself. (Take $A=-I$ for an extreme example.)

Comment: Ok, so just to make sure, this means that if $AA^*$ is positive definite, A is invertible? Do you by chance have any source or proof for that?

Comment: If $AA^*$ is positive definite then $\|A^*x\|^2=x^*AA^*x>0$ for all nonzero vectors $x$, i.e., $A^*x\ne0$. So $A^*$ is invertible, and hence so is $A$ (with $A^{-1}=((A^*)^{-1})^*$).

Comment: Yay great, thanks! I'm currently formulating an optimization problem where the determinant of $A$ must be nonzero, and this means that I don't need to introduce a new constraint since $AA^* > 0$ is already fulfilled :)